# How to get a list of unique unknown words from a google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula

I am creating a google sheet to analyse a bunch of keywords from a google sheet.
https://gyazo.com/4db16f1db553c4d45881fef909340d59
The keywords came in cells of text which I broke up using the split function.

What I want to create is a list of unique keywords from this sheet.

I tried using the Unique function, but it only checks a row for unique values and not a sheet. The screenshot below is of my failed attempt.
https://gyazo.com/8aa1a84dec385b6cad635774769f8c23

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
=ArrayFormula(unique(transpose(split(concatenate("|"&A:Z),"|"))))
```

**Explanation:** `concatenate("|"&A:Z)` (combined with `ArrayFormula`) creates a list of all the values in there, prefixed with "|" as separator.

Then the `split()` function separates all those values again, based on the same delimited, in a single row.

`transpose()` ensures you have one row per value, instead of columns, since the `unique()` function will consider entire rows (now, each row is one column wide).

Comment: Hi Benoit, I am a little confused on where to put this formula / what to replace with it.

Comment: The formula needs to be placed in the first cell of the range (column) where you want to see the list of unique words. The `A:Z` range in the formula needs to point at  your initial range where all the raw data is, I believe it's `Hashtags!A1:Z100` in your case, from your screenshots.